Inversion of ranks in Nemenyi Diagram created using Orange
I have a code that I use to generate Nemenyi Diagram. Here is the version:
import Orange 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
names = ["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7"]
avranks = [3.94,4.94,3.33,3.56,5.94,4.30,4.52]
cd = Orange.evaluation.compute_CD(avranks,48,alpha="0.05") #tested on 48 datasets 
print("cd=",cd)
Orange.evaluation.graph_ranks(avranks, names, cd=cd, width=9, textspace=1.2)

plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.95, bottom=0.15, left=0.15, right=0.95)  # Adjust margins as needed
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12}) 
# Adjust line properties after calling plot()
for line in plt.gca().lines:
    line.set_linewidth(1.25)  # Set the desired line width (e.g., 1.5)
plt.show();

The result is:

I have received a request that says: "It looks like rank calculation is inverted. The lower the rank the better the algorithm."
I have tried using the REVERSE option with graph_ranks, but it doesnt work. It inverts the algorithms, whereas the axis labels also get inverted.That is, A5 shifts to the left side (that's what I need), but the scale above also gets reversed.

Please check your input. If you have seven methods (A1-A7), how can their average ranks be larger than 7?

I have updated the code now. Thank you for pointing out the issue. I want A5 to appear on the left side (first point).. whereas the top scale should nt be changed.

This is not an answer. You should write it as comment.
